# How can avoid including zeros when using the opencv Filter2D function?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the `Filter2D` function in `opencv-python` on a satellite image that have several black-fill values (zeros) around the edges. Here you can find an example of what I am talking about: https://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/truecolor.jpg

When I use `Filter2D` on that image, the pixels from the black-filled area are considered valid values, creating edge artifacts. How can I not include the zeros in the calculation? For example, in IDL I can use the "missing" and "invalid" fields like this:

```
output = CONVOL(input, kernel, /EDGE_TRUNCATE, MISSING=0.0, INVALID=0.0, /NAN, /NORMALIZE)
```

and avoid issues at the edges,but I cannot find a similar functionality in opencv. How can get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example to do mean filtering, but probably can be adapted to you problem:

```
im[maskInvalid] = 0
maskValid = np.logical_not(maskInvalid)

# mean filter, but without dividing by the number of elements
imFilt = cv2.boxFilter(im,-1,(51,51),normalize=False)
# count the number of elements that you need to devide by
maskValidTmp = cv2.boxFilter(maskValid.astype('int'),-1,(51,51),normalize=False)
imFilt[maskValidTmp!=0] /= maskValidTmp[maskValidTmp!=0]
imFilt[maskValidTmp==0] = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no mask or ignore parameters in the OpenCV function. However, the only artifacts will be *outside* the image, i.e., in the black region. Whenever the anchor of the filter (by default, the middle pixel) is on the edge but over a black pixel, it will add the filtered result to that pixel. But when the anchor is over the top of the image, the black values won't add anything to your filter. So, a simple solution is to create a mask with the black values and remove those from your filtered image.

Edit: Ok so from the [IDL convol docs](https://harrisgeospatial.com/docs/convol.html):

> Tip: The use of the `INVALID` keyword is equivalent to treating those values as 0.0 when computing the convolution sum. You can use the `NORMALIZE` keyword to exclude these points entirely.
>
> Tip: If `NORMALIZE` is set and your input array has missing data (the `INVALID` or `NAN` keywords are set), then for each result value the scale factor and bias are computed using only those kernel values that contributed to that result value. This ensures that all result values are comparable in magnitude, regardless of any missing data.

So from here we see that the points are "excluded" by treating the invalid pixels as 0, but then biasing the sum by dividing by a different number of pixels than the kernel size (namely, the number of pixels that are valid).

This isn't possible in OpenCV, at least not with the built-in filtering methods, because OpenCV does not normalize the filtered result. See [in the docs for `filter2D()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) that the equation is just simple correlation, and there is no division.

Now, what you *could* do is manually normalize. This isn't too hard. If you created a mask, where the values were 1 inside the normal image, and 0 outside the image, then a [`boxFilter()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#boxfilter) with the same kernel size as your `filter2D()` would produce the counts of pixels inside the kernel window at each location. This would be one way to normalize the image. Then you can simply mask this `boxFilter()` result, so that the values outside the image bounds are ignored, and then finally, divide your `filter2D()` result by the masked `boxFilter()` result (ignoring where the `boxFilter()` result is 0 so you don't divide by zero). That should do exactly what you want.

Edit2: So here's a concrete example. First I'll define a simple image (7x7 with a 5x5 inner square of 1s):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
```

And we'll keep to a simple filtering example with a Gaussian kernel:

```
gauss_kernel = np.array([
    [1/16, 1/8, 1/16],
    [1/8, 1/4, 1/8],
    [1/16, 1/8, 1/16]], dtype=np.float32)
```

Now first, filter the image...

```
filtered = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, gauss_kernel)
print(filtered)

[[ 0.25    0.375   0.5     0.5     0.5     0.375   0.25  ]
 [ 0.375   0.5625  0.75    0.75    0.75    0.5625  0.375 ]
 [ 0.5     0.75    1.      1.      1.      0.75    0.5   ]
 [ 0.5     0.75    1.      1.      1.      0.75    0.5   ]
 [ 0.5     0.75    1.      1.      1.      0.75    0.5   ]
 [ 0.375   0.5625  0.75    0.75    0.75    0.5625  0.375 ]
 [ 0.25    0.375   0.5     0.5     0.5     0.375   0.25  ]]
```

And this is what we expected...the Gaussian blur of a bunch of 1s should be well, 1s. And then we have some decay at the edges, both inside the image and outside in the zero area. So we'll create a mask; in this case it's just the same as the image. And then we'll do a box filter over the mask to get the correct scaling values:

```
mask = img.copy()  # in this case, the mask is identical
scaling_vals = cv2.boxFilter(mask, -1, gauss_kernel.shape, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
print(scaling_vals)

[[ 0.111  0.222  0.333  0.333  0.333  0.222   0.111]
 [ 0.222  0.444  0.666  0.666  0.666  0.444   0.222]
 [ 0.333  0.666  1.     1.     1.     0.666   0.333]
 [ 0.333  0.666  1.     1.     1.     0.666   0.333]
 [ 0.333  0.666  1.     1.     1.     0.666   0.333]
 [ 0.222  0.444  0.666  0.666  0.666  0.444   0.222]
 [ 0.111  0.222  0.333  0.333  0.333  0.222   0.111]]
```

Note that if you multiply this by 9 (the number of vals in the kernel) then we'll get the exact "number of non-zero pixels around a pixel location". So this is our normalizing scale factor. Now all there is to do is...normalize and remove the stuff outside the image borders.

```
mask = mask.astype(bool)  # turn mask bool for indexing
normalized_filter = filtered.copy()
normalized_filter[mask] /= scaling_vals[mask]
normalized_filter[~mask] = 0
print(normalized_filter)

[[ 0.  0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0. ]
 [ 0.  1.265  1.125  1.125  1.125  1.265  0. ]
 [ 0.  1.125  1.     1.     1.     1.125  0. ]
 [ 0.  1.125  1.     1.     1.     1.125  0. ]
 [ 0.  1.125  1.     1.     1.     1.125  0. ]
 [ 0.  1.265  1.125  1.125  1.125  1.265  0. ]
 [ 0.  0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0. ]]
```

Now these values aren't perfect, but neither is the biased sum. Note even in the IDL docs they state:

> you should use caution when analyzing these values, as the result may be biased by having fewer points within the kernel.

So you're not going to get perfect results by scaling like this. But, we can do better! The scaling factor we used only used the number of points, but not the actual weight associated to each of those points. For that, we can filter the mask with the associated weights. In other words, just run `filter2D()` over our mask instead of the image. Obviously, dividing our image by this just turns all the values into 1; and then we mask. And we're done! Don't get confused by this example since the mask and the image are identical---dividing the filtered image by the filtered mask in this case gives us 1, but in general, it's just a better scaling than the box filter.

```
mask = img.copy()
scaling_vals = cv2.filter2D(mask, -1, gauss_kernel)

mask = mask.astype(bool)  # turn mask bool for indexing
normalized_filter = filtered.copy()
normalized_filter[mask] /= scaling_vals[mask]
normalized_filter[~mask] = 0
print(normalized_filter)

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Alexander, the problem is that the values close to the black edge will be decreased because of the convolution. So, a simple masking will not work.

Comment: Indeed, but what's the other option? If you "ignored" those pixels, that's the same thing---those parts wouldn't add into your convolution, so the values would be less. Do you want it so that the convolution kernel can never overlap the black regions instead then? I.e. the edge pixels near black not have a convolution result? To put it another way, when you normally do convolution, the edges of the image are padded with black unless you specify otherwise. Would you be using a different flag, like border reflect or border repeat instead?

Comment: Yes, correct. In IDL, those zero values are just ignored, so that the pixels close to the edge will not decrease.

Comment: I see; what IDL does is normalize by a smaller number of pixels in the missing area. Then no, I don't think there's a comparable way to do that (cleanly) in OpenCV, as OpenCV doesn't normalize the pixels in a convolution.

Comment: @Knulph I edited my post and came up with a solution that should work to give you the same values. It seems a little convoluted, but it's actually pretty simple. It's taking me awhile to give an example as I'm not getting a perfect mask since the supplied example image is `jpg` and not `png`.

Comment: @Knulph I further modified my answer to provide an example. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

Alexander,

first of all, thank you so much for your detailed explanation and testing code. I believe I understand the rationale you used, and I have derived this code that seems to be doing exactly what I needed:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


a = np.array([[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
              [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
              [10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
              [20.0,20.0,20.0,0.0,0.0],
              [30.0,30.0,30.0,30.0,30.0]], dtype=np.float32)

kernel = np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.float32)

filtered_a = cv2.filter2D(a, -1, kernel)
mask = (a > 0)
if np.any(~mask):
    scaling_vals = cv2.filter2D(mask.astype(np.float32), -1, kernel)
    filtered_a[mask] /= scaling_vals[mask]
    filtered_a[~mask] = 0
    scaling_vals = None
    mask = None

print a
print filtered_a
```

which produces:

```
[[  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 17.5          0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 22.8571434   22.8571434   26.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 23.33333397  23.33333397  24.2857151   26.          30.        ]]
```

Comment: That looks great, but I would be a little cautious with adding that bias so you can divide by really small numbers...could give some weird precision errors; dividing by `1e-10` is the same as multiplying by `10000000000` so just be careful with that. It might be better just to mask them manually.

Comment: I modified the code to reflect your comment. Thanks again!